# Window.open() not working + how to close a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so when someone goes onto my codepen --> https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/gXMrJO , the window opens itself. Basically a infinite loops opening and closing itself, this is my JS/ jQuery code:

I added comments in the code on the codepen.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  if (document.URL !== "https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/ooLxmQ/") {
    window.open("https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/ooLxmQ/");

  }
  var one = 1;

  if (1 === 1) {
    window.open("https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/full/ooLxmQ/");
    one += 1;

  }
  if (one !== 1) {
    window.close();

  }
});
```

Why doesn't the window open?

Also if i wanted to close the current tab because i just opened a new one, would i just use `window.close()`?

Comment: If you wish to use the `jQuery` library it would be a good idea to include it to your codepen.

Comment: Okay i figured out how to get it so it automatically opens, how to make it so it doesn't need permission, and closes the previous window?

Comment: Okay now how do i close the current window?

Comment: Not really sure why you would want to continuously open a new tab and close the old one other than for annoyance and testing this with google chrome makes it worthless as it blocks the new window as a pop-up. If you write things like this you will lose clients trust in visiting your pages/websites/profiles but if it's that important to you then you would take a look at this [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/7NBsYQ2u) I hope you don't plan to write things like this in the attempt to irritate people.

Comment: Well it was on codepen and i did figure out how to open it infinitely. I am making a codepen that you input a number of tabs and it opens then closes that amount of tabs, you can view it here @ https://codepen.io/Mike-was-here123/pen/QOEGOj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open an infinite number of web pages, just do this:

```
while (true) {
  window.open("insert web page");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `window.close();` isn't a function? I'm reading different from this documentation [**MDN web docs  window.close();**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

Comment: It depends on what version you're using, ES6 or ES5. it also depends on what compiler you are using.

Comment: I am using repl.it as a compiler, the website doesn't support `window.close();`

Comment: Okay well if you are using **repl.it** here is a [**working demo**](https://repl.it/Nmuk) this example isn't closing the current window, this is an example of `window.close()` so it's wrong to claim it isn't a function when it clearly exists no matter what ES5/6 is being used. If anything you should say it isn't supported if you find it isn't working/functioning rather than claiming it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Also, `window.open();` cannot be used alone, so that's why I said that it isn't a function. Sorry that I didn't clarify that.

Comment: What do you mean it cannot be used alone? The real problem is that the OP is checking if the document.url is a match to the domain and path which will return false since most online editors use an external/iframe to execute the source so if the OP checked with something like `alert(document.url);` or used `console.log(document.urll);` then the reason for the condition never returning true would be known. Lack of debugging.

Comment: Also using `window.open();` alone will open a new tab **about:blank** so I'm very confused to what you mean by it cannot be used alone. [**Example**](https://repl.it/Nmuk/1)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `window.close();`